# Closed XML setting pivot table report layout to Tabular?

Tags: c#, pivot-table, closedxml

Currently have a project where I am dumping a result set of data to an excel and creating pivot table with this raw data using Closed XML

I cannot seem to get the report Layout to set and persist as tabular

Below is a sample of the code I am using to implement this

```
var ptSheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("PivotTable");
var pt = ptSheet.PivotTables.Add("PivotTable", ptSheet.Cell(1, 1), range);
        pt.SetLayout(XLPivotLayout.Tabular);
        pt.Layout = XLPivotLayout.Tabular;
```

'SetLayout' & 'Layout' seem to make no changes to the layout of the pivot on save of the excel. Are other settings required to be toggled?

Comment: Pivot tables are a recent addition in ClosedXML and are still work in progress. If a feature is missing or broken, log an issue on the Github repo, or even better a pull request.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding this solution in case someone has similar issue.

I found adding the following line of code to my above example made the pivot table layout appear as tabular

```
pt.ClassicPivotTableLayout = true;
```

Not the most elegant solution but works for my use case